# Unable to resolve Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My ASP.NET Core project is about a year old and uses EF Core with Postgres. I ran a `dotnet migrate` which converted my old `project.json` to a new `csproj`. And now the project no longer compiles. Specifically, when I run a `dotnet restore` I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
```

Here is what my `csproj` currently looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How can I resolve this dependency issue and get back on track? (Ideally, I want to future-proof as much as possible)

Comment: I think you should upgrade Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to 1.1.0-preview4-final version by run cmd: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 1.1.0-preview4-final

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should have mentioned I am on a Mac and I don't think Install-Package is an option for me. I've never used it before.

Comment: You can use this command from the Package Manager Console commands in Visual Studio or change to <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" /> in .csproj file.

Comment: Your target framework is still 1.0, try changing to 1.1... `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>`

Comment: @HaHoang yes, that was it. Put it in an answer below and I'll mark it answered.

Comment: @Adrian thanks that wasn't key but I took your advice also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be upgraded Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to 1.1.0-preview4-final version by:

- Run the following command in Package Manager Console

  Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 1.1.0-preview4-final
- Or manually change to `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />` in .csproj file

Hope this help!